# Ubuntu 15.10 no wifi, Bluetooth, USB, sound

Tags: wireless, usb, bluetooth, broadcom, 15.10

I have a laptop dell vostro 3560. It had Ubuntu 15.04, but after a fresh install of ubuntu 15.10, WiFi, Bluetooth, USB ports and sound don't work. I have wired internet connection though.

```
$ lspci
```

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] (rev ff)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
```

`modprobe wl` gives this error. What does that means?

```
$ sudo modprobe wl
```

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:578 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.2.5-040205-generic/modules.dep.bin'
```

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Regarding wireless drivers http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Comment: It IS one question since everything worked fine on the previous version without me manually installing any drivers and now after fresh install nothing works, so I think it's all connected and there must be some simple solution

Comment: It is three questions regarding  wifi, bluetooth and usb. All have answers.

Comment: @Pilot6 you may wish to weigh in: http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14609

Comment: @Tim No, answer is not same. Even bluetooth and wifi is the same physical chip, but there are two separate solutions for them. The sound issue is the 4th one, that is not related at all.

Comment: And also there is some mainline unsupported mainline kernel  `4.2.5-040205-generic`. I suggest OP to boot with an Ubuntu kernel.

Comment: It looks like either today or yesterday they released an updated kernel for Ubuntu. I'd try upgrading to the latest kernel and seeing if that helps anything. (idk if it's the kernel or what but Ubuntu has been completely freezing ever since I updated to 15.10, and the logs haven't shown anything.)

Comment: well... after kernel update the stated problems were solved but now I have a new one. The system gets stuck at ubuntu logo and doesn't boots unless I go to recovery mode -> resume. Every solution I could find is for older ubuntu versions and doesn't work for wily. Should I create a new thread for this matter?